# Theme Installation

Tags: theme, installation, magento-2.1.3

I downloaded a free theme Ves Fasony.
I copied and pasted the file in this directory *app/design/frontend/*

But in the theme that I downloaded, there is a `code` folder and is no `code` folder under `app` folder in magento 2.1.3

Where should I put it? Am I installing it in a wrong way?

Comment: Create `app/code` folder & put inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To install the theme in magento 2 manually you must need to know about directory structure of magento2.**

- like for design you need to put files in app/design folder
- like for modules you need to put files in app/code folder
- also for sql file you need to import that sql file in your database
- For images you need to put your images file in pub/media folder

So here if code folder is not there you need to create it .

For more reference how to install theme manually follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995942/installing-magento2-theme

Answer (score 1):

You have to create it. So it will look like:

```
App/code/Ves/Setup/

App/design/frontend/Venustheme/fasony/
```